# Announcement: StackExchange Review Scheduled To Happen In Next Month

Tags: discussion

A member of the StackExchange Community Team mentioned to me that our site is schedule for a public review, most likely in the next month.

The good news is that our stats overall are looking good. Most questions get answers, we have a solid core of contributors, and our number of visits is okay. The main area, in the statistics, that needs work is the number of questions asked per day.

[image: Area51 Stats]

The main problem with the site is its quality of questions and answers *as it relates to Q&A*. That's not to say people are asking uneducated questions or giving thoughtless answers, quite contrary. Most of the questions and answers are composed with a great deal of thought and consideration.

There isn't a clear picture of where exactly we should draw the line, and we need to come together and determine exactly where that line is and clarify the rules of this site.

This decision doesn't belong to just a few moderators; instead, it is something that must come from us all as a community.

*To shake things up a bit, I'm going to close questions that I don't feel fit the guidelines for good Q&A questions.*

*If you think a question shouldn't be closed, please follow the advice given in the comments, edit the question to improve it, and post a follow-up question on meta to discuss the case for reopening it.*